# Hide enclosed divs using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a step by step system that is hiding and showing divs depending on the step you are on, here's jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {    

    // prepend a 'previous' button to all form-rows except the first
    $('<button>').addClass('previous').appendTo($('.form-row').not(':first'));

    // hide all form-rows, but not the first one
    $('.form-row').not(':first').hide();

    // hide on last step
    $('button.next').last().hide();

    // add the submit button to the last form-row
    $('<input>').addClass('submit').prop('type', 'submit').val('My Dashboard').appendTo($('.form-row:last'));


    // handle the previous button, we need to use 'on' here as the
    // previous buttons don't exist in the dom at page load
    $('.form-row').on('click', 'button.previous', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div.form-row').hide().prev('div.form-row').show();
    });

    $('button.next').click(function(e) {
        // prevent the next buttons from submitting the form
        e.preventDefault();
        // hide this form-row, and show the next one
        $(this).parent('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();
    });    

});
});
</script>
```

Here's my html:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <h2 style="float:left;margin-left:7px;">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  </h2>
  <h2 style="float:right;"><?php echo $counter; ?> of <?php echo $total; ?></h2>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="module-area" style="margin-top:0px!IMPORTANT;">
    <div id="modules-top"></div>
    <div id="modules-repeat">
      <p class="training"><?php echo the_sub_field('introduction'); ?></p>
      <?php if(get_sub_field('training_images')): ?>
      <?php while(has_sub_field('training_images')): ?>
      <img class="training" src="<?php echo the_sub_field('image'); ?>" />
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <p class="training"><?php echo the_sub_field('conclusion'); ?></p>
      <button class="next"></button>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:5px;" id="modules-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This was working until I added the a few div's inside the `<div class="form-row">`. How can I get it to hide the enclosed divs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `parents('div.form-row')` instead of `parent('div.form-row')`

Comment: Or `.closest('div.form-row')`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

Try:

```
$('button.next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var _parent = $(this).closest('div.form-row');

    _parent.hide();
    _parent.next().show();
});
```

I like to break things up when it comes to long jQuery chaining for readability.

Comment: Try putting that where you have `$(this).parent('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();`. In javascript, newlines don't matter

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS I've tried to put that in but it doesn't work. As soon as I added the extra divs the step by step process stopped working so it must be that!

Comment: Updated my answer** Also, by default grabbing a parent and doing `.hide()`, it doesn't matter what settings div's/whatever inside have, they will automatically be hidden. Are you sure the HTML is structured correctly??

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS This is the actual page I'm working (not browser tested!) http://frontiersharpsafety.com/v1/training/sharps-safety/ . The next button has completely stopped working.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS That's a different section although it uses the same functionality. The only difference is the extra divs I've added inside the parent div. When I take out all the divs within the parent it works.

Comment: @Rob, did my answer work for you or did you mean to accept this answer?

Comment: @Lian Yep, I formatted all my code and tried again and it worked, no idea why it didn't the first time!

Comment: Just realized I completely overlooked something... (also why I never use .parent(). If you used `.closest('div.form-row')` that would of fixed it as well, lol